# Can't set headers after they are sent error. I am not calling render()/json() twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have trying to return a response to the client after an entry has been made to the database. I have written the following code to achieve the required result, however I am getting

**Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.**

I am not calling *response.json()* or *response.render()* twice anywhere for this response. So why is this error occuring?

```
router.post('/yolo', jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {

    response = res;
    shortUrl = shortenTheUrl(req.body.textBoxValue);
    var insertDataInTableQuery = "INSERT INTO `WinGoku`.`ShortenedUrlsTable` (`OriginalUrl`, `ShortUrl`) VALUES('"+req.body.textBoxValue+ "', '"+ shortUrl +"')";
    runSQLQuery(insertDataInTableQuery, sendResponseToClient);
});

function runSQLQuery(query, callbackFunction) {
    connection.query(query, function(error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(query);
            console.log("QueryError: "+ error);
            if(callbackFunction != undefined)
                callbackFunction({type: "alert", errorMessage: error});
        }

        if(callbackFunction != undefined)
            callbackFunction({type: "alert", errorMessage: "successful"});
    });
}

function sendResponseToClient(queryExecutionResult) {
    console.log("1: "+ queryExecutionResult["type"] + " 2: "+ queryExecutionResult["errorMessage"]);
    response.json({shortenedUrl: shortUrl, type: queryExecutionResult["type"], message: queryExecutionResult["errorMessage"]});
            ^
            error here. Can't set headers after they are sent
}
```

Comment: When an error occurs in `runSQLQuery`, the callback will get called twice. As an aside, your code seems to be susceptible to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be calling response.json() twice, if the query fails and instead of returning from the error clause, it executes query successful clause as well. So you must put a return statment at the end of error clause. This should fix the problem.

```
function runSQLQuery(query, callbackFunction) {
    connection.query(query, function(error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(query);
            console.log("QueryError: "+ error);
            if(callbackFunction != undefined)
                callbackFunction({type: "alert", errorMessage: error});

            return; // this should fix the problem!
        }

        if(callbackFunction != undefined)
            callbackFunction({type: "alert", errorMessage: "successful"});
    });
}
```

Comment: Not only that, but `response` is a global variable (!). Even with no errors, situations can occur where `response.json()` is called multiple times on the same response object.

Answer (score 0):

you are not ending response so that error is comming.
Try modifying your code like this:

```
router.post('/yolo', jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {
    response = res;
    shortUrl = shortenTheUrl(req.body.textBoxValue);
    var insertDataInTableQuery = "INSERT INTO `WinGoku`.`ShortenedUrlsTable` (`OriginalUrl`, `ShortUrl`) VALUES('"+req.body.textBoxValue+ "', '"+ shortUrl +"')";
    runSQLQuery(insertDataInTableQuery, sendResponseToClient, function(data){
     res.end();
    });
});
```

Comment: `runSQLQuery()` takes two arguments, not three.

Comment: add runSQLQuery(query, callbackFunction, success) {}
and then check if the method completes.